# How do I get the previous arrival time in Java

Tags: java, transactions, format

I'm working on a program with several classes. I'll post all the full five classes if requested, but here's what happens. It compiles without compilation errors right. But the program sets arrival times to zero for a transaction whenever a customer has more than one transaction. Obviously, each customer that makes multiple transactions doesn't arrive at 0. So, here's the problem. I identified the line of code. Its a constructor:

```
  public Transaction(String[] line){
    this(
      Integer.parseInt(line[0]),
      Integer.parseInt(line[1]),
      //check returning customer
      line[2].equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line[2]),
      line[3]
    );
  }
```

That's the second constructor in that class. There are five classes. Now, no matter how hard I try to figure out something I can change the third value (line[2]) to be stored in a variable to hold a value so long as its "" so that when there's an actual different value, it will assign that only to a variable and then that variable would become the arrival time until it was explicitly stated differently. This doesn't work. All I do is change the number by changing the 0 to another uniform value, and its not supposed to be a uniform value. I look at another part of the program in a different class, where I iterate through the list of transactions:

```
    String [] line = input.nextLine().split(",");
  Transaction transaction = new Transaction(line);
  transactions.enqueue(transaction);
}
//Serving all customers
while(!(transactions.isEmpty())){
  //help and dequeue first person
  Transaction lastTransaction = transactions.dequeue();
  //save info
  Customer lastCustomer;
  if(customers.size()>0){
    Customer previousCustomer = customers.get(customers.size() - 1);
    if (previousCustomer.getCustID()==lastTransaction.getCustID()){
      //any returning customer
      lastCustomer=previousCustomer;
      lastCustomer.addTransaction(lastTransaction);
    }
    else{
      //every new customer
      lastCustomer = new Customer(lastTransaction.getCustID(), lastTransaction.getArrivalTime(), previousCustomer.getTimeDeparted());
      lastCustomer.addTransaction(lastTransaction);
      customers.add(lastCustomer);
    }
  }
  else{
    //first customer
    lastCustomer = new Customer(lastTransaction.getCustID(),      lastTransaction.getArrivalTime(), 0);
    lastCustomer.addTransaction(lastTransaction);
    customers.add(lastCustomer);
  }

}
```

I want to check the last transaction and see if the arrival time is blank, and if so, not update it. I'm now trying to do exactly that rather than change the number. But I don't see where I can change the condition. Maybe I'm just tired late at night and need some shut eye. But I think if I focus on that while loop, I'll be able to change the condition so that it accommodates a variable. Its just that I'm having trouble figuring out what that condition would be. Does there even need to be a condition? For example, if I change the else to an else if, and add a condition, then what do I put as the else? etc. So I don't see what I can do to make this work. If I change the first while loop, I can't see what I could possibly change that would be effective.

I'll post code for all five classes if necessary. BTW, if this sounds like I'm not putting in enough effort let me know. I am kind of tired right now so that might be the case.

Here is my output:

```
 Customer ID: 1 
 Arrived: 0 
 Waiting Time: 0 
 At Teller: 0 
 Transaction Time: 7 
 Departure time: 7 


Customer ID: 2 
 Arrived: 0 
 Waiting Time: 7 
 At Teller: 7 
 Transaction Time: 3 
 Departure time: 10 


Customer ID: 3 
 Arrived: 0 
 Waiting Time: 10 
 At Teller: 10 
 Transaction Time: 7 
 Departure time: 17 


Customer ID: 4 
 Arrived: 8 
 Waiting Time: 9 
 At Teller: 17 
 Transaction Time: 2 
 Departure time: 19 


 Customer ID: 5 
 Arrived: 9 
  Waiting Time: 10 
  At Teller: 19 
 Transaction Time: 3 
 Departure time: 22 


Customer ID: 6 
 Arrived: 0 
 Waiting Time: 22 
 At Teller: 22 
 Transaction Time: 5 
 Departure time: 27 


Customer ID: 7 
 Arrived: 0 
 Waiting Time: 27 
 At Teller: 27 
 Transaction Time: 9 
 Departure time: 36
```

Once I'm done with that, I can worry about putting it into table format, but that's not what I think I need help with yet.